# Not able to do password less ssh in GCE centos box

Tags: hadoop, google-compute-engine

I was trying to set up hadoop in gce centos box. But when i was trying to copy my public key from my server to client [ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub [USER]@[CLIENT]] , it is throwing permission denied error. I tried almost everything found in the internet , bit no success. Can anybody suggest me if i need to add anything in the firewall in gce console or i have to do something to make it work

Answer (score 1):

The regular process is to generate the SSH keys locally and then add the public key to the server in order to be able to SSH into an instance.

It seems like you're doing the opposite: adding the key from the server to the client. To have a better understanding of the issue I think we'll need a little more info. Can you provide detailed configuration steps for your current setup?